# Is it possible to login automatically in google drive or Dropbox with static credentials, without login popup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-drive-api

I have a requirement in my project like this .

Client will place a images in his google drive account/dropbox.I need to display those images in my application from drive/dropbox.I need to give client's credentials in the code by static.So is there any way so that I can use dropbox without login or some where I can set default login ID Password and automatically do login.

I'm not sure it gets possible.Can any one give me a suggestion.Is it possible with google drive or dropbox or box or any one without using server .

Answer (score 0):

The Google Drive API does not support username and password as credentials. You must use OAuth2:

https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/auth

That said, you could get a refresh token once, store it in your app, and use that to generate access tokens to be used in the requests.